# Curl CA Certificate issue

Tags: curl

I tried to access a particular url using curl which in return is giving the typical error 60 in return.

curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

i tried replacing the current certificate with http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and also tried with the certificate created using http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt?raw=1

Still no luck. All the other other urls are working except this one.

But the Url is working fine on Chrome and IE9 .
Operating System used Windows 7 and CentOS.

Comment: which url are you connecting to?

Comment: I'm sry , cant disclose the url.

Comment: Ok. If you go to the url in Firefox and download the certificate, then export the signing certificates and upload that to your server and set that as the CA cert of the curl connection?

Comment: Woohoo. . . problem solved. i dint check in Firefox. It forced me to add exemption to that url (it was not a severe risk case, but untrusted certificate notification popped up). And it was only Firefox where i found a working certificate issuer's link . :)

Comment: I really don't see the point of down voting this one. Please do nothing if not interested. People have different problems to be solved. It needn't be always at the SAME LEVELS !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed Firefox during testing. From firefox i was able to retrieve the exact CA certificate's link, where the certificate used was stored. I added that portion to my existing certificate. It solved the issue.

PS: Chrome and IE directs you to same location while searching for the certificates. But Firefox has their own stuff.

Thnx Lex for reminding about Firefox. :)